# Can't add cortana to dev bot framework

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana

This isn't a code related question. On https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels , i am unable to add the cortana channel to my bot because it wont save my cortana configuration. It keeps saying "The form is not complete" and
"Please check to make sure you have filled in all required fields" when all the fields are clearly filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but currently there is a bug in the Cortana config page with the Display name and Short description fields. These fields have a limit of 30 and 50 characters respectively. However they come prefilled with information from your bot settings, and if your bot description is longer than 50 characters, it will block your submission and won't say which field is the problem. Make sure your Display name is 30 characters or less and your short description 50 or less.

Update: This bug should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly why it wouldn't let me save(save button was disabled). However, I now get a "Missing Token" error message after clicking the enabled save button..